# MapServer mapfile: Issue getting scalebar to display, no errors in log

Tags: javascript, gis, mapserver, map-files

Here is the code for SCALEBAR in the mapfile:

```
SCALEBAR
  IMAGECOLOR 255 255 255
  LABEL
    COLOR 0 0 0
    SIZE SMALL
  END
  STYLE 1
  SIZE 100 2
  COLOR 0 0 0
  UNITS MILES
  INTERVALS 2
  TRANSPARENT FALSE
  STATUS ON
END
```

No glaring/noticeable errors in /tmp/mapserver3.log. What would the issue be?

EDIT1: had to change status from ON to EMBED.